# Using QgsVectorFileWriter

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, wfs

I have a Python script to load features from a WFS in my QGIS project within a certain buffer. The loading-part of the features works. After that, step 2, I want to save al new loaded feature to an already existing shapefile in my explorer. I use QgsVectorFileWriter for this. Nevertheless, the **features don't seem to save in the already existing shapefile**.

It is important for me to save all new features in an already existing shapefile ('44048_GRAR_adressen.shp'), because this shapefile (with this specific name) is connected to a GIS-system.

**My full script:**

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

QgsProject.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
#
####################################
####### load local data#############
####################################
rootAlgemeen = '//eiger/Orbit server/data/gemeente/44048/Achtergronden/'
boundingboxbuffer = QgsVectorLayer(rootAlgemeen + 'BoundingBox/Boundingbox44048_buffer.shp','boundingboxbuffer','ogr')  
boundingbox = QgsVectorLayer(rootAlgemeen + 'BoundingBox/Boundingbox44048.shp','boundingbox','ogr')
gemeentegrens = QgsVectorLayer(rootAlgemeen + 'Grenzen/Gemeentegrens/Apn_gemeentegrens.shp','gemeentegrens','ogr') 
  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([boundingbox,gemeentegrens,boundingboxbuffer])
#
###########################################
#########Roots for WFS#####################
###########################################
WFSrootBBbuffer = '&SRSNAME=EPSG:31370&cql_filter=Intersects(SHAPE,POLYGON((89157.6794 177564.9059, 89157.6794 189210.326, 104002.6140 189210.3269, 104002.6140 177564.9059, 89157.6794 177564.9059)))'
WFSrootBBErfgoed = '&SRSNAME=EPSG:31370&cql_filter=Intersects(geom,POLYGON((91657.679 180064.905, 91657.679 186710.326, 101502.614 186710.326, 101502.614 180064.905, 91657.679 180064.905)))'
WFSrootBB = '&SRSNAME=EPSG:31370&CQL_FILTER=Intersects(AdresPositie,POLYGON((91657.679 180064.905, 91657.679 186710.326, 101502.614 186710.326, 101502.614 180064.905, 91657.679 180064.905)))'
#
############################################
#### Add WFS Adressenregister to project####
############################################
rootGrarWFS = 'https://geo.api.vlaanderen.be/Adressenregister/wfs?VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TypeName='
GrarWFS = QgsVectorLayer(rootGrarWFS + 'Adressenregister:Adres' + WFSrootBB , 'WFS Grar' ,'wfs')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(GrarWFS)
#
#########################################
########Save WFS as known shapefile######
#########################################
rootGRAR = '//eiger/Orbit server/data/gemeente/44048/Achtergronden/Gebouwen-en-Adressenregister/Shapefiles/GRAR_adressen'
GRARShape = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(WFS Grar ,rootGRAR + '44048_GRAR_Adressen.shp','UTF-8',layer.crs(),"ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected=False)
#
##########################
######## Finished#########
##########################
print('opslaan geselecteerde features in shapes klaar')
```

**QgsVectorFileWriter script so far:**

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(WFS Grar ,rootGRAR + '44048_GRAR_Adressen.shp','UTF-8',layer.crs(),"ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected=False)
```

Can someone help me fix my QgsVectorFileWriter?

I've searched on many website and tried adjusting several values, but it still doesn't work.

The CRS is EPSG 31370, the same of the WFS layer.

Comment: do the types of geometry match in the shapefile? or are you trying to save polygons into a line shapefile?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `writeAsVectorFormatV3`? What is the method returning? Do you want to overwrite or append to the existing file?

Comment: Ian, normally, the types of geometry match. The layers are both point layers.

Comment: Bugmenot, I use this VectorFileWriter because this script is actually someone else's that I'm adjusting. I think 'to overwrite' is the best way. It just want to update the layer with the newest data. I want to run the script once a week to make sure that the layer has the most recent data.